# Maclaurin Expansion of $\frac{x}{\sqrt{4-2x}}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Maclaurin Expansion of $\frac{x}{\sqrt{4-2x}}$ up to order 4.

I really don't know how to do this, I can't find a helpful Maclaurin Series in my formula book to help me.

I want to do $x(4-2x)^{-1/2}$ and use the formula for $(1+x)^p$, but I don't think that works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Computing the MacLaurin series only involves taking successive derivatives.

Comment: See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maclaurin's series is given by

$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$

where $a_n=\left(\frac{f^n(0)}{n!}\right)$

Here $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{4-2x}}$

Differentiate successive & find values of $f^n(0)$ for $n$ up to 4 as your requirement & then use these values to find Maclaurin's expansion.

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't this take quite a while to do?

Comment: do u find some difficulty in solving using my procedure.

Comment: No, I understand it, but wouldn't it take a long time to do? It would be a load of chain ruling, right?

Comment: Yes u r write .This is descriptive type method i m still searching for a generel expression of derivatives for the given function

Answer (score 0):

You can write $x(4-2x)^{-1/2} = x 4^{-1/2} (1-(x/2))^{-1/2}$ and now use the formula for $(1+x)^p$. More details? See also the comment by IB Wiglin.